# .NET Websphere MQ to create a message recognized as JMS BytesMessage?

Tags: .net, jms, ibm-mq

We have .NET MQ client sending messages to MQ queues, it works fine. 
On the receiver end we have a JMS client, which needs to receive BytesMessage. 
I wonder if it's possible for sender to set some MQ headers, so that produced message is always recognized as BytesMessage on receiver end?
Currently it defaults to TextMessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below snippet can be used to write a bytes message.

```
  MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
  msg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_NONE; // Ensures jms_bytes type message is delivered to JMS application
  msg.WriteBytes("HelloWorld in bytes");
  MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
  queue.Put(msg,pmo);
```

Comment: Yes, if MQMD.Format is set to None, then MQ JMS by default creates jms_bytes type message.

Comment: I'm also wondering if it's possible to keep RFH2 header in this case? It looks discarded when I set such format.

Comment: If your intention is add JMS specific RFH2 headers, then you may want to look at XMS .NET API. XMS .NET implements JMS specification in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try something like:

```
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
byte[] serialisedContext= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourMessage);
msg.Write(serialisedContext, 0, serialisedContext.GetLength(0));
```